# Debugging symbols present, but eclipse does not associate them with source code

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, debug-symbols, ns2

I am working on modifying a rather large program (NS2 network simulator), and it would be nice to be able to debug it with Eclipse. I configured the makefiles ( add -g to CFLAGS ) to make gcc generate the debugging symbols, and they are indeed generated, but Eclipse refuses to actually find the code associated with those symbols. I imported the HUGE folder of source code using the "Makefile Project with Existing Code", and when I hit "debug" it runs the program. When I tell the debugger to stop, it often stops in a method I recognize, but when i click on the method's name, it says "source not available" even though the source file where the method is defined is actually open in another tab. I do have all the sources imported into the project. Am I missing something in the make configuration?

^long confusing explanation, I know... see screenshot, :
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/zzz1fu.jpg/

Note that IPKTAgent::deBurst() from the above screenshot is declared in integrated_agent.h -- that is the file I have open in the other tab.

also, when I expand the entry for the executable I'm debugging in the project explorer, it only lists some of the files it is composed of. What gives? (see screenshot, there should be more files on the list, the ones I'm working with are missing).
screenshot:  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/zzz2z.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it. Works for me. The only issue was that I forgot to add `-O0` option to disable optimization; it can be an issue in your case too.

What I can suggest:

- Try to disable optimization
- Check that compiler options you use are *really* applied. You use `CFLAGS`, but I see c++ in tags, so it is possible that you should use `CXXFLAGS` (it can depend on build tools you use)
- `IPKTAgent::deBurst()` is declared in `integrated_agent.h`. But where is it implemented? Check that it is implemented in header and/or you can access to the source file where it is implemented.
- Check that you can debug your executable with gdb
- Try to create simple automake/autoconf based project and check that you are able debug it in gdb and eclipse. You *should* be able.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the suggestions. I'll try them and post an update, I get the feeling it's either the CXXFLAGS thing or optimization.

Comment: My problem was that at first I was trying to play nice and do all this by invoking the config script with the --enable-debug option, which seems like it would work, but clearly it did not. So, I cowboyed it and changed the makefile to say "CXX=g++ -O0 -g" and something similar for gcc. Now that i've shoved the options down its' throat like that, it works great... actually stops at breakpoints and everything. I wouldn't advise people to do kludgy things like this lightly, but it did work for me this time...